# Change only black colored part to white of a colored picture

Tags: css

how do you turn the black portions of a colored picture to white by using css?
I have tried using [invert](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/filter-function/invert) but that inverts every color of the picture.

In my specific use case I have a picture with blue and black colors and I want to turn the black parts into white.

usecase example [png](https://i.ibb.co/9cS1gGh/black-blue.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
img{
filter: invert(100%) hue-rotate(180deg);
}
```